# Unity Compiz Close Window effect does nothing on window close

Tags: unity, compiz

I have Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit and I'm using Unity, I decided to start using the pretty Compiz effects, and they do work, when I open a window, the open window effect works, same with menus, tool tips, etc., and they work with the close window effects too, the tool tips and menus and whatnot burst into flames when they disappear (which is my closing effect)

However when I close an actual window, like Firefox, Nautilus, or another full window, it just closes normal, no flames, and like I said, the other effects are working.

When I minimise windows the effects work, when I open them, it's just when I close them, and like I said the closing effects DO work on menus, tool tips, etc., so it has nothing to do with the effects settings there.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I want my windows to BURN!

Comment: Does ANYONE else have problems with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that this was just a problem with Natty, on Oneiric this was fixed.

Comment: You should *accept this answer*, so it's clear to other people searching that this question has been solved and what the solution is. (You were unable to do so when you first posted it, because you have to wait 2 days between posting your own answer to your question and accepting it.) **In the future, please note that you should [file bug reports as explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs); Ask Ubuntu is [not a good place for bug reports](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).**